# OOP: Private methods vs new class

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, architecture, testunit

if this question was already answered, please tell me; I was only able to find the usual "what's a public/private/protected" question!

So here is my question:
When do I use private methods and when do I create a new class with public methods instead?

Example:

```
class MyActualWorker {
    public function work() {
        $this->helperMethod1();
        $this->helperMethod2();
    }

    private function helperMethod1() {
        ...
    }

    private function helperMethod2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
class MyActualWorker {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->helperObject = new HelperObject();
    }

    public function work() {
        $this->helperObject->helperMethod1();
        $this->helperObject->helperMethod2();
    }
}
```

When do I use the first example, when the second?
For me the primary advantage of the second example is UnitTesting is really easy.

I am grateful for any answer!

Comment: You should use private methods in cases where you don't need to re-use the methods from other classes, and where the methods access variables that are private or only visible to the owning class.

Comment: @Ted Most common use for delegation isn't re-using the methods (those should just be public instead, maybe public static in a helper class), but being able to swap the implementation at runtime.

Comment: True, but swapping can also frequently be managed by interfacing and inheritance in cases where the effect is tightly coupled with the owning class.  Java uses object delegation for most things where the method is not very tightly coupled with the owning class, while C# uses it much more sparingly.  Some of this is programmer preference I think as well.  But if you need to access private variables, I wouldn't recommend delegating to other objects unless you really have to, and then you could pass in the values as parameters.

Comment: Also, delegating to another class is a great idea when you want to pull business logic away from the GUI, and to declutter.  See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you use the first.

The ["*Delegation Pattern*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) (which is using sub-objects) is a great way to have different implementations of methods you can swap out at runtime - but if you don't need that, it's just unnecessary overhead.

Another common case are what I call "library methods", that is, methods that are not tied to any objects but stateless an just perform some calculations. Those can be delcared `public static`and moved to an abstract class. YOu don't create objects for that kind of relationship though (just classes with static methods), so it's entirely different to your example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have another question: Let's say I want to calculate anything. In Java I know there is java.lang.Math containing many static methods. This seems quite logical so far. But now I also could be an extreme OOP guy and say: "Hey, only a calculator can calc, so let's have a calculater object provide all these methods!". I see how this is more effort, but it still seems like a very valid approach...?

Comment: @TimJoseph In PHP, those methods are avialable without any prefix, because it hasn'T always been able to do any OOP. The `most php way`of doing this is using a namespace (http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), but you can also create an abstract class (just how it is in Java), see second part of my answer)

Comment: @TimJoseph DId you just edit your comment? ANyway, as for the "Hardcore OOP way": Use the Singleton Pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Yea sry, I accidently pressed the submit button (edit: and just now again). I see your point! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm surprise that nobody talked about testability. In my opinion, it is the factor to consider when creating a new class.

Comment: Can you please explain this further or provide links? :)

Comment: links about... what exactly?